# iOS spotify sample auth and playback code on swift

Tags: swift, xcode, spotify

I'm trying to recreate the sample code from objective c in the spotify sdk to Swift.

Here's my code

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let kClientId = "8b6f7fc911d844dd8abfb08551423d9f"
    let kCallbackURL = "byse-test-login://callback"
    let kTokenSwapURL = ""

    var session:SPTSession?

    var player:SPTAudioStreamingController?

    func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBQJYs_f6NkSJvYf9EPgF2QoNyAZjLnas4")
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
        var loginURL = auth.loginURLForClientId(kClientId, declaredRedirectURL: NSURL(string: kCallbackURL), scopes: [SPTAuthStreamingScope])

        // Opening a URL in Safari close to application launch may trigger
        // an iOS bug, so we wait a bit before doing so.
        delay(0.1) {
            application.openURL(loginURL)
            return
        }

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        // Ask SPTAuth if the URL given is a Spotify authentication callback
        if (SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandleURL(url, withDeclaredRedirectURL: NSURL(string:kCallbackURL))) {
            SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, tokenSwapServiceEndpointAtURL: NSURL(string: kTokenSwapURL), callback: { (error, session) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    println("*** Auth error: \(error)")
                    return
                }

                self.playUsingSession(session)
            })

            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    func playUsingSession(session:SPTSession) {
        // Create a new player if needed
        if (self.player == nil) {
            self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController()
        }
        self.player?.loginWithSession(session, callback: { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                println("*** Enabling playback got error: \(error)")
                return
            } else {

                SPTRequest.requestItemAtURI(NSURL(string: "spotify:album:3vGtqTr5he9uQfusQWJ0oC"), withSession: session, callback: { (error, album) -> Void in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        println("*** Album lookup got error \(error)")
                        return
                    }
                    self.player?.playTrackProvider(album as SPTAlbum, callback: nil)

                })
            }
        })

    }
```

and so far these are my errors.

[could you identify what may have caused this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdZwF.png)

Thanks guys, really appreciate the help